# Change item if new ones are available

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a list:

```
List<Article> articles = new Arraylist<>;
```

I add this list to my adapter, and add the adapter to my recycler view.

In my recycler view there are always 5 items. When I'm refreshing recyclerview with swipe refresh listener, I'd first like to check if they are all the same or some of them changed (new ones are available), and change those which are needed (let's say the first three are new, and leave the other two the same as they were before, without setting new data). If items are the same and there are no new ones, don't change anything, and if all are changed then append whole recycler view with new items.

So, there is always a range of 5 items. I just want to append the new items if needed, or leave it as it is if not needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code used for adapter as well as the way you are checking if the objects have changed.

Comment: Could you please post some code for us to look at?